# Which files does jacoco-maven-plugin scan by default

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

What does a plain jacoco-maven-plugin, without any configuration on inclusion and exclusion analyze, as in which types of files are included into the analysis and which ones are skipped.
I didn't manage to find any documentation on this if you do please refer it in the comments below.

Comment: The ywo places to read are the [jacoco documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/index.html), including the [maven-plugin specifics](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html), and baeldung.com which provides a detailed walkthrough](https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco). The plugin is ultimately just a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The jacoco-maven-plugin will generate coverage for class files in the build output directory specified by the ${project.build.directory} property in  maven. It includes execution data from ${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec by default.